# Using Scanner.next() in a set method and trying to call it on an array element

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'll try to explain this as best I can.

First off, here's the code. It is split into two files:

GetAndSet.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetAndSet {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String myString;

    public void getInput(){
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
        myString = scan.next();
    }

    public void setString(String myString) {
        this.myString = scan.next();
    } 
      // Is the problem here? I realise I have set myString equal to
      // scan.next() twice, but I couldn't see an alternative way.

    public String getString() {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

GetAndSetTest.java

```
public class GetAndSetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[] newArray = new Object[1];

        newArray[0] = new GetAndSet();

        System.out.println(newArray[0]);
    }  
}
```

What I am attempting to do here is create an array of objects, with each element having a string declared by the user.

I have tried to `Scanner.next()` in conjunction with a set method, and so far no errors have been thrown, but I seem to be unable to call `getInput()` on `newArray[0]`, or any method for that matter.

The result of `System.out.println(newArray[0]);` is:

```
GetAndSet@55f96302
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

indicating that no input has been provided.

Again, thank you for your answers, and I'm sure you'll ask for more information if you need it.

Comment: what is the difference between your getInput() ans setString() methods?
from looking I get that in getInput() user enter a string value....but what is setString() for?

Comment: Without overriding toString() printing the object gives you a memory address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your array element to a object of type `GetAndSet`.

```
newArray[0] = new GetAndSet();
```

What you may want to do is to create a object, call `getInput` on it to read the input from the scanner and then sets the array element to `getString`. Something like:

```
GetAndSet gas = new GetAndSet();
gas.getInput();
newArray[0] = gas.getString();
```

And then the standard `setString` should be just assigning the `myString` to the parameter passed.

Comment: Okay, I did exactly that, and it works, however, something new has popped up. It doesn't allow more than one word. This is the output: 
`Please enter a string: "Hello World"
"Hello
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)`

Comment: How do you expect it to accept multiple inputs when there is no loop anywhere in the code? Try to use one of the looping constructs - like `for` or `while` depending on your need.

Comment: Okay, I see. I just thought a string could contain any amount of words without having to loop through.